# How to add a cookie plugin to a static HTML site (archived wordpress page)?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, cookies, wget

I am hosting an old website that is used as an archive and is usually not edited anymore. I converted the Wordpress page to a static HTML page by using wget. This means I do not have to apply new updates everytime wordpress releases newer versions.
Due to a new German law I have to add a Cookie-Note on every subpage.
As the website is static I do not have the opportunity to add a plugin so I have to do it manually.

Is there a way to automatically overlay a cookie-note on every subpage?

Best,
Hannes

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, by simply adding this script to your head of each page or the pages where you want to display the cookie message:

```
<!-- Start Cookie Plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.CookieHinweis_options = {
      message: 'Diese Website nutzt Cookies, um bestmögliche Funktionalität bieten zu können.  
      Wenn Sie diese Website nutzen, stimmen Sie der Verwendung von Cookies zu.',
      agree: 'Zustimmen/Agree',
      learnMore: 'Datenschutzerklärung',
      link: 'http://your.html', /* Link zu den eigenen Datenschutzbestimmungen */
      theme: 'hell-unten-rechts' 
      /* weitere Theme-Optionen sind hell-unten-rechts dunkel-unten oder dunkel-oben */
     };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/website-tutor/cookiehinweis/script.js "></script>
<!-- Ende Cookie Plugin -->
```

Comment: Nice, it would be great if you can click on link, left side "This answer is useful".. :)